# BLE HM10 - Set Password - Android Pairing Problem

Tags: arduino-mega, android, ble

I have developed an application on Android, which connects to a Bluetooth HM10, launches commands, and turns LEDs on and off through my Arduino. All of this works properly.

So, I want to make Bluetooth secure, so that nobody can connect to it, and keep it busy and I can't connect myself.

To do this, from my Serial Monitor I execute the corresponding configuration commands, but I never get it to link correctly on my Android.

I have tried many options, to no avail:

**OPTION 1)**

- AT+ROLE? = Ok+Get:0 (Slave or Periphe)
- AT+TYPE2 = Ok+Set:2 (Auth with PIN)
- AT+PASS123456
- AT+RESET

**OPTION 2)**

- AT+ROLE? = Ok+Get:0 (Slave or Periphe)
- AT+TYPE3 = Ok+Set:3 (Auth and bond)
- AT+PASS123456
- AT+RESET

In both cases (and more failed tests), I see the BLE device on my Android Bluetooth.
I give it to connect and the window to enter the password pops up.
I introduce 123456
And it always tells me that it could not be linked.

Any ideas for why?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an expert but the AT commands seems a bit strange. e.g. I would expect to enter a new PIN with `AT+PASS123456`. Perhaps the space is part of the PIN in your case. Just a guess. Also, the question mark after PASS is used (AFAIK) to read the PIN, not to set it. Just some guesses, without knowing much about AT commands. Perhaps it works. Cheers.

Comment: The ROLE command also has a question mark. But as 0 is the default it is not a problem. PASS is just an alias for PIN so the official AT-command to set a new PIN is `AT+PIN123456`.

Comment: As you set the type to 3, the module requires authentication, but (I guess) the password/PIN is still 000000.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I have modified the initial message, because yes, I put it wrong. The password setting is without "?"
And, no, I am not putting any spaces after the password. I have made sure they are only 6 digits, clean, with no spaces.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer
`AT+PIN?` it never gives me a value of OK, with the default pin.
And `AT+PIN123456` does not react the Bluetooh module for that command.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I have tried `AT+TYPE1`, `AT+TYPE2` and `AT+TYPE3` right now, with Pin `000000` and I cannot link it

Comment: I wrote about the space before the PIN. I don't know if AT commands may have spaces between their parts. I only know the compact versions. `ATPIN?` does not respond? What about the other commands? Do they respond? Have you tried `AT+RENEW` before the other commands? That would reset to the factory setup.

Comment: For the HM10 model, the AT commands above do not respond. They are not supported. Its specification in the DataSheet (https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf) defines that the commands are `AT+`. They never have spaces between the command and the values to assign. The commands and the values to be assigned are continuous. And the `AT+RENEW` command, effectively, resets to factory values, which, I have tried many times.

Comment: `ATPIN?` was a typo I made in a text I repeated from your comment. I know that AT+ is the AT-command prefix. I also know he spec. But I was not sure if spaces are allowed, sometimes specs and reality differ ;-).  Your last comment lets me think, that the communication between the Arduino and the HM10 does not work. I have no idea, why. You could edit your question and add the code that runs on the Arduino. And a schematic of you setup would also be helpful.

Comment: Don't say that the setup works without authentication. In this case the Module communicates with the arduino. When you try to configure the HM10 from the serial monitor that's the other direction. Or do you configure the HM10 direct from your PC/Laptop without a Arduino between?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer The communication between Arduino and HM10 works perfectly because if I run `AT+PASS123456` and then turn off the arduino, turn on the arduino and do an `AT+PASS?` returns `Ok:Get:123456`. So the communication is correct. In addition, without securing the HM10, I can send commands from Android, I turn off LEDs and turn on LEDs on my protoboard, via bluetooth. So it works. It only fails to secure the HM10

Comment: When I say that the communication works without authentication, I mean that from my Android application, I pair with the HM10 (automatically, from programming, without password or anything), I launch commands, the arduino picks them up, and I turn LEDs off and on. At the moment that I secure HM10 (by setting it with an authentication configuration), I cannot pair with the HM10 from the Android application because it asks me for a password and the password never works.

Comment: I configure HM10 from Arduino, using the Serial Monitor (as I mentioned in my initial post).

Comment: You could use the Serial monitor with the Arduino in between the PC and the HM10 or you can connect the HM10 direct to the PC. That's what I asked for. You also commented that the `AT+PASS?` does not respond. Now you comment that it responsed with the correct PIN. What is true? --- I'll stop this discussion now. Sorry, but I have not the time to guess what you might want to say. And my english is not good enough to correct yours. --- One final tip: perhaps the bluetoth authenticaten mechanism differs between the peers.

Comment: I can't connect my HM10 to my computer, because it's a Mac, and Macs can only connect to factory Bluetooth.
At all times I have said that the execution of `AT+PASS` commands both to obtain the password and to define a new one, have always worked well. And when I say that they have worked well, it means that the HM10 module has answered "Ok" for all cases.
The problem, as the post describes, is that from an Android device, I cannot pair the HM10.

Comment: I live similar problem.
http://kio4.com/arduino/161_HM10_BLE_Actualizar.htm
Your page is very very successful.All the instructions are working.
I will use the pio for opening the door of my car.
Thank you very very much for you help. I have a problem but.I give password to module and give the typr 3 or 2 .I try this but iphone asks for paşrşng password.I wrote wrong password but system connects and works.Beaceuse of this issue I can not use on my car because, if I wrote wrong pin it connects also.There is no password protection on the car than.so I cannot solve the password problem.What must I